# Closing the last report in a collection

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I made a collection which stores multiple instances of a report being opened with different filters.

If I try to close the most recently opened report, it is removed from the collection but does not close.

All other reports are both removed from the collection and closed.

How can I close the last report?

```vb
Private Sub CloseButton_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rptcol As New collection
    Set rptcol = ReportCollectionModule.rptCollection
    For i = 1 To rptcol.Count
        If Me.Hwnd = rptcol.Item(i).Hwnd Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    DoCmd.Close acReport, rptcol.Item(i).Caption, acSaveNo
    rptcol.Remove i
    Set ReportCollectionModule.rptCollection = rptcol
End Sub
```

The ReportCollectionModule is a basic setter and getter.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private myRptCollection As New collection

Public Property Get rptCollection() As collection
    Set rptCollection = myRptCollection
End Property

Public Property Set rptCollection(thiscollection As collection)
    Set myRptCollection = thiscollection
End Property
```

The reports are added to the collection as follows:

```vb
Private Sub ID_Click()
    Dim rpt As Report
    Dim rptcol As New collection
    Set rptcol = ReportCollectionModule.rptCollection
    Set rpt = New Report_ProductTable
    rpt.RecordSource = "Product Table"
    rpt.Filter = "[ID]= " & Me![ID]
    rpt.Visible = True
    rpt.Caption = DLookup("[ProductName]", "Product Table", "[ID] = " & Me![ID])
    rpt.Requery
    rptcol.Add rpt, CStr(rpt.Hwnd)
    Set ReportCollectionModule.rptCollection = rptcol
    Product_Name.SetFocus
    ID.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `DoCmd.Close acReport, rptcol.Item(i).Caption, acSaveNo` will probably not work as you intented because the `Docmd.Close object, objectName` will close the object by it's name not by it's caption/title.

If you close the report by it's `Name` `using docmd.close object, object name`, the first instance that Access can find in the memory is closed until no more to close.

`ReportCollectionModule.rptCollection.Remove report.Hwnd` should close the instance you specify. Please post how you are managing/adding forms, you may have a flaw there.

Instead of using a class, make `rptCollection` as a public object/dictionary and just use `rptCollection.remove hwnd`

Comment: I updated my original post with the code for adding forms to the collection.

If I convert the collection to a Dictionary instead, how would I go about initiating that in the module? I believe you have to use the following:

`Dim MyDict As New Scripting.Dictionary`
`Set MyDict = New Scripting.Dictionary`

but I can't create that object outside of a sub like I can with the collection.

Comment: @Grandiloquence ideally make public functions that takes a report object as parameter and adds to your global dictionary. Within the helper function you can check if your global dictionary variable needs to be initialised. Point is you need to have a public static/ singleton collection object.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using. It closes all forms but the one which it is calling from:

```
Private Sub CloseAllForms()
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For lngLoop = (Forms.Count - 1) To 1 Step -1
        If Me.Name <> Forms(lngLoop).Name Then
            DoCmd.Close acForm, Forms(lngLoop).Name
        End If
    Next lngLoop
End Sub
```

You can do the same for reports:

```
Private Sub CloseAllReports()
    Dim lngLoop As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For lngLoop = (Reports.Count - 1) To 1 Step -1
        If Me.Name <> Reports(lngLoop).Name Then
            DoCmd.Close acReport, Reports(lngLoop).Name
        End If
    Next lngLoop
End Sub
```